# How to get the same curve with Matlab numerical function and ezplot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have the following symbolic function :

```
f(x)=(2*5^(1/2)*atanh((5^(1/2)*x)/150))/3 - 100/x
```

If I plot it with :

```
figure(2);
vMax=150/5^(1/2);
ezplot('(2*5^(1/2)*atanh(x/vMax)/3 - 100/x',[0.1, vMax]);
axis([0.1 150/5^(1/2) 0 3]);
view([90 -90]);
```

I get the following figure :

[image: ezplot figure]

As you can see with `view(90 -90])`, I invert (Ox) and (Oy) axis : this is because I wan to plot the inverse function of analytical expression above.

Now, I would like to find the same plot but with numerical values. for this, I did :

```
syms f x;
f=(2*5^(1/2)*atanh((5^(1/2)*x)/150))/3 - 100/x;
ht=matlabFunction(f);

vMax=150/5^(1/2);
% Speed array
v_start=0.1;
step=0.0001;
v_final=vMax;
% Construct array vNew
vNew=v_start:step:v_final;
%Plot results : Speed vs Time
figure(1);
plot(vNew,ht(vNew));
axis([0 vMax 0 3]);
view([90 -90]);
```

With this code snippet, I get the following figure :

[image: numerical function]

Here, I don't understand two things :

1. Where does second curve (at the top of first one) come from ?
2. After launch this script, I get the following warning :

**Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored**

at the line : `plot(vNew,ht(vNew));`

I know that complex numbers appears with `atanh` function for `-infty < x < -1` and `1 < x < +infty` but in my case, I have taken :

```
 0.1/vMax <= x/vMax <= 1
```

with `vMax = 150/5^(1/2)`, so the interval is `[0.1/vMax,1]` and into this range, `atanh(x/vMax)` has real values.

So logically, I should not find complex values when I execute the command :

`plot(vNew,ht(vNew));`

### Update

Error fixed since I was out of range -1 < x < 1 by taking `vMax=150/(5^(1/2))+20` for computation and also in `axis([0.1 150])`, i.e there were conflicts between both.

Comment: I don't get the extra line. Make sure you clear the figure before plotting.

Comment: @jodag modify for figure(1) plot : axis([0 150 0 3]);
view([90 -90]);
you will see it normally

Comment: Tested on both MATLAB 2015b and 2017a. No extra lines on either even after changing axis view. Maybe add `clf(gcf)` after `figure(1)` to make sure you aren't seeing old results.